# Hyperlink from Plist in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, search, plist

I have a button in my app when clicked is supposed to take you to the website of the business which is stored in a plist. I can get the button to work with this code:

```
 -(IBAction)search:(id)sender{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```

Now how can I manipulate this code to call the website from a plist already established.

Answer (score 2):

Get the link string from the p-list.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSString * urlString = dictionary[@"TheKeyPath"]; // theKeyPath referring to the key that you assigned to the url string in the p-list
```

Then very simple...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it like this but the button never appears to do anything, I wrote an NSLog and it does click the button but does not send to safari.

```
-(IBAction)search:(id)sender{
    NSString *searchsite = [resultDic objectForKey:@"Search"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchsite]];
}
```

What is confusing is I have a call function wrote like this and it works just fine.

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {

    NSString* yourActualNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",resultDic[@"Phone"]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourActualNumber]];
}
```